# File inbound connector

Tags: mule

I have a question on the File Connector in Mule. Does the file inbound connector process the files in the order that they have arrived ? Does Mule change the order of processing the files?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of the order of processing you should set your flow to use **processingStrategy="synchronous"** and choose the correct Comparator

Here is a good [example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-file/3.0.0/org/mule/transport/file/comparator/OlderFirstComparator.java)